# Coldfusion Session Timeout Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion

I have a sessionTimeout for my project like this

```
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
```

for some reason pages on a deeper level inside of other folders are timing out before the 5 hours within like 20 minutes... Do I need to insert this in all application.cfc's to make it work correctly? I thought they all trickle down from the top level.

Comment: This isn't part of your issue, but please stop using `"` and `#` when they're not necessary. You can simply write `<cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)>`

Comment: "I thought they all trickle down from the top level.". No. Only the first "upstream" Application.cfc encountered is used. That can inherit code from other files, but you actively have to make the Application.cfc extend the other file. Sounds like you're not doing that.

Comment: so by posting that line in the next files should take care of it right?

Comment: "basically in all the application.cfc's"

Comment: If a request needs that setting, then it needs to be in the Application.cfc that that request will be using. That's all there is to it. So put the setting in any Application.cfc file that will need it. It's not more complicated than that.

Comment: Also remember that you cannot override the session timeout set in the ColdFusion Administrator with a *longer* value. For example, if your CF Administrator has a session timeout of 20 minutes, and the session timeout in your Application.cfc is 5 hours, your actual session timeout will be 20 minutes. However, the reverse will work (have a long timeout in CF Administrator and a short timeout in Application.cfc).

Answer (score 1):

A template or component file will use the first Application file it finds moving backward through the folder structure until it reaches the root.  So as long as there is not an application.cfc or application.cfm between your template and the root the timeout should work.

Comment: so if I have other application.cfc with no timeout inside of folder then I need to add that line also right?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are extending the previous Application.cfc, or possibly using the same application name, your previous setting will no longer exist. You could also increase it in the CF Admin to make it global.